# IF statement executes when condition is false C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

- I tried disabling the button at first but that didn't work
- Therefore I created a variable to prevent it from running the code inside the IF.  For some weird reason it doesn't work, when I try to click it before the sleep it executes right after the time is over.

So if I click the Button

- one time it sleeps for 2 seconds,
- if I double click it it sleeps for 4 seconds (etc) despite that it should only sleep for 2 seconds.

This should make so the code would only executes after the buttons are enabled again.
(The buttons being disabled is just for the looks)

Note:Variable "button_enabled" is global

```
 private void senha_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button_enabled == 1)
        {
            button_enabled = 0;
            wait_label.Show();
            senha_a.Enabled = false;
            senha_b.Enabled = false;
            senha_c.Enabled = false;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            wait_label.Hide();
            senha_a.Enabled = true;
            senha_b.Enabled = true;
            senha_c.Enabled = true;
            button_enabled = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You click twice. Windows puts two "mouse click" messages into your message queue. You get one of them and process it. In doing so you spend 2 seconds. Only after you have returned from your click handler, you take the next message that's been waiting for you in the queue, and also process it, also taking two seconds. Your program is single-threaded, and it processes its messages sequentially. So no, the `if` statement does not execute when the condition is false.

Comment: Exactly. The `Thread.Sleep()` call completely freezes the main thread and the second click is executed only after the 2 seconds are over.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you want. Does "How to ensure that a click on a Button only executes some statements if a condition is true?" match your question? Or is your intent: if a user clicks a button a task is perforemd that has some delay. I want to make sure that the user does not executes this task twice by double clicking or by clicking a second time within a treshhold of two seconds.

Comment: Ty all guys, and someone fixed it with await instead of a thread sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it

```
 private async void senha_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button_enabled == 1)
        {
            button_enabled = 0;
            wait_label.Show();
            senha_a.Enabled = false;
            senha_b.Enabled = false;
            senha_c.Enabled = false;

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            wait_label.Hide();
            senha_a.Enabled = true;
            senha_b.Enabled = true;
            senha_c.Enabled = true;
            button_enabled = 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, I've read the other comments and this worked perfectly according to them too!!!